# Qual é a diferença entre Guard() e Middleware()?

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

Andei notando que ambos fazem, basicamente, a mesma coisa... Posso ter entendido errado, mas qual seria a diferença entre os dois no Laravel?

Answer (score 1):

Eu andei pesquisando sobre o assunto e vou deixar aqui as informações resumidas, e links para mais detalhes.

### Middleware

Segundo a [documentação do Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/middleware) (em tradução livre) é:

> O middleware fornece um mecanismo conveniente para inspecionar e filtrar as solicitações HTTP que entram em seu aplicativo.

A função do middleware é interceptar a solicitação entre a entrada na aplicação e o controlador. [Seguindo o Ciclo de Vida da Solicitação](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/lifecycle) a requisição, após ser montada pelo Kernel e identificada sua rota pelo roteador, ela passa pelas pilhas de Middlewares que foram adicionados a esta rota.

Esses middewares vão inspecionar a requisição antes que ela chegue ao controlador, isso permite validações como a de autenticação, onde a solicitação apenas é permitida seguir ao controlador quando há um usuário logado. Caso contrário, a requisição é abordada e um erro é retornado ao usuário.

Se a requisição passar pelos middlewares, ela deve ser executada no controlador e no caminho de volta deve passar novamente pelo middleware, isso permite também interceptar as respostas dos controladores.

Um middleware bem comum é o `auth` que sua principal tarefa é invocar o guarda para resgatar o usuário logado.

### Guard

Segundo a [documentação do Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication) (em tradução livre) é:

> Os guardas definem como os usuários são autenticados para cada solicitação.

Os guardas definem como deve ser feito a identificação do usuário logado em cada requisição. Isso quer dizer, como o usuário será identificado nas requisições, através de um token no cabeçalho ou um cookie e sessão.

Além da identificação do usuário, guardas devem definir seus provedores, que é o mecanismo responsável por obter os dados do usuário após a sua identificação, por padrão é usado o Eloquent para obter os dados do usuário do banco de dados, mas pode ser facilmente alterado por um provedor personalizado.

Guardas são normalmente invocados por middlewares como o `auth`.

---

Acredito que parte dessa confusão na separação entre middlewares e guards vem do momento no ciclo de vida em que esses atores entram em cena, pois os dois são executados antes que a requisição chegue ao controlador.

Agora que temos conhecimento desses dois mecanismos e suas responsabilidades, podemos simplificar nossa conclusão em: **Middlewares** interceptam a requisição para aplicar validações e **Guards** são responsáveis por identificar o usuário logado em cada uma dessas requisição.

Recomendo também que leia este [tópico no StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65875215/what-is-the-difference-between-middleware-vs-guards-vs-gates-policies-in-laravel), que me ajudou muito a entender esses e outros conceitos do Laravel.